How to create BLE connect mobile app when the esp32 is the server? android studio
I need getting the data from esp32 and receive data in my mobile app.This is the BLE Based.I have ESP32 Is a server.I am create the mobile app in android studio.But i get the output encode format.how i solve this.

You can use an npm package react-native-ble-manager for it.
It also have an example app https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/tree/master/example . Clone the app and go through the code. it will resolve all your query.

ERROR  BeManager could not be started. [TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of null]
ERROR  [retrieveConnected] unable to retrieve connected peripherals. [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConnectedPeripherals' of null]
DEBUG  [startScan] starting scan...
ERROR  [startScan] ble scan returned in error [TypeError: Cannot read property 'scan' of null]
ERROR  [retrieveConnected] unable to retrieve connected peripherals. [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConnectedPeripherals' of null]
I got this error

open a new question for this and also add your code to it.
